# Integration by parts in $ \int_a^b t^3\sqrt{1+2t^2}dt $

Tags: calculus, integration

So I have an integral:

$$
\int_a^b t^3\sqrt{1+2t^2} dt
$$

My first instinct here is to integrate by parts.

So I choose:

$$
u= \sqrt{1+2t^2}
$$
$$
v'= t^3
$$

so

$$
u' =  \frac{2t}{\sqrt{1+2t^2}}
$$
$$
v = \frac{t^4}{4}
$$

using the form:

$$
\int_a^b f(x)g'(x)dx = f(x)g(x)\vert_a^b - \int_a^bg(x)f'(x)
$$

but I end up with another integral that I can't evaluate:
$$
\frac{t^4\sqrt{1+2t^2}}{4}\vert_a^b  -  \int_a^b \frac{t^5}{2\sqrt{1+2t^2}}
$$

I've tried integrating by parts again, and I've tried substitution, and I've tried integrating by parts by selecting the root to be antidifferentiated. I'm lost on this one.

Comment: I think I may have solved this. Integration by parts was I think a poor choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest approach is to  try substitution: $t^3\sqrt{1+2t^2}=t\,t^2\sqrt{1+2t^2}$. This suggests trying $u=1+2t^2$. Then $du=4tdt$, and
$$
\int_a^ t\,t^2\sqrt{1+2t^2}\,dt=\frac14\,\int_{1+2a^2}^{1+2b^2}\frac{u-1}2\,u^{1/2}\,du=\frac14\,\int_{1+2a^2}^{1+2b^2}\frac{u^{3/2}-u^{1/2}}2\,du=\left.\frac14\, \frac{u^{5/2}}5-\frac{u^{3/2}}{3}\right|_{1+2a^2}^{1+2b^2}
$$

Comment: Yeah that's almost exactly what I ended up doing.

Comment: also, how did you do the long bar on that u^3/2 term in LaTeX?

Comment: With \left and \right. If you right-click on the equation you can choose to see the LaTeX code.